# Multiboot USB with UEFI/BIOS support for Windows, Ubuntu and MacOS

Tags: linux, windows, macos, multi-boot, bootloader

I'd like to do the following, on a single USB stick:

1. Have installations for Windows, Linux (Ubuntu) and MacOS
2. Be able to install Windows and Linux in both BIOS and UEFI modes (BIOS in case the system does not support UEFI)
3. Be able to boot from the USB in UEFI/non-UEFI mode (from my computer's boot menu, I can choose whether I want to boot to the USB stick in UEFI/non-UEFI mode), which should launch something like a bootloader, which would allow me to:

a) Install Windows

b) Install Ubuntu

c) Install MacOS (in this latter case, I'd like this option to actually open Clover bootloader, from where I would be able to select an option to install MacOS).